# parsing SOAP response in C#...not understanding the XML namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Please excuse me, I'm new to SOAP and C#.  I can't seem to figure out how correctly set the namespaces to find a node in a SOAP response.

Here's the response if the web service query returns empty:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:VXWSResponse xmlns:ns="vx.sx">
            <ns:List ns:id="result" />
        </ns:VXWSResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here's the response if it returns data:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:VXWSResponse xmlns:ns="vx.sx">
            <ns:List ns:id="result">
                <ns:Badge>USER DATA</ns:Badge>
            </ns:List>
        </ns:VXWSResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I just need to know if the  tag is present.

Here's what I have so far.

```
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("ns", "vx.sx");
manager.AddNamespace("id", "result");
xmlNode badge = xml.SelectSingleNode("//id:Badge", manager);
XmlNode result = xml.SelectSingleNode("//ns:result", manager);
```

Both nodes return null.  I've looked at good number of other articles on this site, but I'm not seeing how to correctly address the namespaces in the response XML.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you really need to parse SOAP by hand? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have no control over the web service and this needs to run on CE 5 / .NET 2, so I'm not sure using a Service Reference is possible.  I ONLY need to test whether the <Badge> tag is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the id is an attribute of the List Node, not a namespace.

I Edited my answer this to check for the Badge element as that is all you seem to want to look for.

```
        XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        manager.AddNamespace("ns", "vx.sx");

        XmlNode badge = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:Badge", manager);

        if (badge == null)
        {
          // no badge element
        }
        else
        {
            // badge element present
        }
```

Comment: that did it.  knew it was going to be something simple.  thank you!